# Android - take picture - onActivityResult returns immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

In my App I would like to take a picture. The current Fragment is within a TabHost.

Within a fragment I start the camera action with:

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult( takePicture, 1);
```

In my MainActivity I have the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
       if( imageReturnedIntent == null) { 
           // immediately coming here when my OWN app is singleTop or singleTask
```

When my App contains an Activity with launchmode singleTask or singleTop, then onActivityResult *immediately* returns with imageReturnedIntent is null. When I remove the launchmode in my App, then it works again.

How can I fix this?

What I read on the internet is that the activity that is launched (so, in my case the Camera App) should not have a launchmode singleTop or singleTask.

Question: how can my own Activity (having launchmode singleTop or singleTask) get an onActivityResult from a Camera App?

Notice: in Android 5.0+ this works fine. In Android 4.x not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do hope someone gives a better answer than this brute-force answer to starting the Camera App from your Activity that is launched with 'singleInstance' or 'singleTop'. So, I will remove this answer if anybody has a better solution.

You can start a seperate activity - that will do the interfacing to the camera app. Yeah - I feel a bit ashamed devising this solution. In the end it works.

OK, in the Manifest file you add:

```
<activity  
    android:name  = "StartMedia" 
    android:label = "StarterMedia" 
    android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

The class contains this code --- and don't forget the finish():

```
public class StartMedia extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent takePciture= new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult( takePciture, 2);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       if( imageReturnedIntent == null) { 
           Logger.v( "intent is null - action ...  ");
           return ; 
       }
       switch( requestCode) {
       case 1:
       case 2:
           Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           String fileName = cursor.getString( columnIndex); 
           Logger.v( "Your Path:" + fileName);
           // DO something with the result
           cursor.close();
           break;
       }
       finish();  // important - otherwise it hangs your app
    }
}
```

Bottom line: there must be a better solution to this. If not, this may be your escape.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other
>   activities to be part of its task.

see here
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

and the `startActivityForResult` launches new activity in the same task.

So, if a task is started for an activity in singleInstance mode, then Android is unable to launch new activity in the task.

You should use `singleTask` mode instead. Is is much like `singleInstance`, but allows other activities to be launched on the task.

on android >=5.0 you will have another problem with `singleInstance` mode:
you always have `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: Thank you, this gives insight.